# Android animate and resize Fragment on drag

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an `Activity` that holds a `Fragment` and other `Views`. When showing the `Fragment`, it is shown as full screen (`match_parent`). The behavior I am looking for is dragging the `Fragment` down to minimize it so it appears as a floating view with a height of `100dp` on top of the `Activity` (check YouTube player animation as a reference).

Also, child views need to change position depends on if `Fragment` is fullscreen or floating mini state

Since I have little to no experience on advanced view animations. Would love to get some references or code samples on how to achieve this.

For now, I am trying to achieve this using `GestureDetectorCompat` while manipulating the `ViewGroup` `LayoutParams`.

Comment: have you tried it using bottomsheet as it might resolve the dragging issue???

Comment: this might help - https://github.com/burhanrashid52/YoutubeUX

Comment: @Debu Github link looks interesting! will check it out thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need use CoordinatorLayout and BottomSheetBehavior.

Use CoordinatorLayout as your activity container and add BottomSheetBehavior to your fragment container

Sample of activity code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Next open fragment from activity with FragmentManager:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.your_fragment_container, YourFragment(), null).commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

Next add to fragment code:

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    // get behavior from fragment container
    val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view.parent as ViewGroup)!! 
    // listen change behavior state for change position of child views
    behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            changeHeaderState(newState)
        }

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {

        }
    })
    behavior.apply {
        // init state
        state = STATE_COLLAPSED
        // doesn't hide your fragment on swipe down
        isHideable = false
        // height of the bottom sheet when it is collapsed.
        peekHeight = view.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.id.floating_view_100dp)
    }
    onCollapsed()
}

private fun changeHeaderState(newState: Int) {
    when (newState) {
        STATE_COLLAPSED -> onCollapsed()
        STATE_EXPANDED -> onExpanded()
    }
}

private fun onCollapsed() {
    // animate on collapse
}

private fun onExpanded() {
    // animate on expand
}
```

Comment: Hey @princeparadoxes, How can this help with dragging the fragment from fullscreen to floating and vice versa?